# An elementary problem in probability: Calculating $P((A \cap B^c \cap C^c) \cup (A^c \cap B \cap C^c))$ under given conditions

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I need to find $P((A \cap B^c \cap C^c) \cup (A^c \cap B \cap C^c))$ given that

i) $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1,4$

ii) $P(A \cup B)=0,8$

iii)$P(A \cap B \cap C)=0,3$

The thing is that i try to use the inclusion exclusion principle one the expression but i quickly get lost in it without an idea on how to proceed (the numbers not of a big importance of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be complicated but I was able to solve it graphically by using a simple venn diagram. Here's what I learned: If $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1.4$ then we know the middle $P(A\cap B\cap C)$ wasn't counted 2 extra times. $1.4-.3-.3=.8$ is the probablity left to be dispersed between A, B and C outside of the center.

Using $P(A\cup B)=.8$ we know that $P(C\cap A^c \cap B^c)=.2$ leaving us with $.6$ probability left to be dispersed among A and B. An important thing to note here is should any of the probability land in $A \cap B \cap C^c$ then it'll be counted twice and it has double weight towards our $.6$ remaining probability. Fortunately, there is only one solution that satisfies these conditions and keeps the total probability 1. With a necessary $.5$ remaining in the total diagram and a $.6$ still needing to be dispersed through A and B, we must have $P(A \cap B^c \cap C^c)\cup P(A^c \cap B \cap C^c)=.4$ and $P(A \cap B \cap C^c)=.1$

Sorry I was in a rush to post this answer before work, hope it helps!